# PBI - Direct Query and Oracle table function

Tags: oracle, powerbi

Currently having to transfer some existing reports in Cognos into PBI, we have some challenges:
We would need to use direct query + a table function, else we need to redesign everything on DB side, which is not expected.
The main challenge here is that it seems that we are not able to pass dynamically to the query any parameter (like a user's choice or "slicer"), and not even the username of who is currently running the report.
Is there any solution for this?
Any improvement planned in the future in PBI?
Thanks!
Vinc

Comment: Hi all, in addition to the original question, I would have also the following: is there any official "PBI website" where I would be able to see the upcoming improvements planned for PBI? Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2021wave1/power-bi/

Comment: Thanks Jon ! It will be helpful